# jmeter: how to use while loop inside a loop

Tags: loops, csv, while-loop, jmeter

my JMeter plan is

```
-- Loop controller (set to 3)
  -- while controller(set to "${Dataitems}" != "<EOF>")
    -- using CSV for  reading the data items
    -- HTTP requests
```

now issue is that after completing the while loop , thread is  getting stopped  . I know this is controlled in CSV config "Stop thread on EOF" =true will make thread to stop. But my requirement is that after iterating through my csv , I want control to passed to outer loop  which will run based on the variable i provide in my case 3 so all request will run for all the data items i provide in csv for three times.

To achieve i tried to set

1. "Stop thread on EOF" = false , then its started running lopp for intinte times
2. "Stop thread on EOF" = ${Var1} , where var1 was declared  in test plan , but still loop was running infinite times

Can some provide an insight on how to handover control from while loop to outer loop?

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, While controller will keep running until the condition fails.

Unfortunately, in your case, you need to set below condition to reiterate the CSV file values.

```
'Recycle on EOF?' to TRUE
```

So, While controller will never exit as you can not use any condition there (to fulfill your requirement).

The only way I can think to make your requirement work is - to use 2 Loop Controllers.

(Outer) Loop Controller (set to 3 as you had said)

(Inner) Loop Controller (set to no of rows in CSV)

I get the output like this. My CSV file has 3 rows with the values A,B,C. They are called 3 times by the outer loop controller.

[image]

If you do not want to hard code the number in the loop controller, use a variable & find the no of rows using beanshell and set the value to the variable.